# Ionic - Center text vertically in item-list with item-avatar class

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I try to add a Ion-List to my apllication with items build like |Image|Text|Button

The Image and the Button get centerd vertically, but the text does not.

I tried some CCS found on the Internet, which works fine in Browser preview but not on a real device (Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, Android 4.1.2)

`style="position: absolute;   top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);"`

**Code**

```
    <ion-content>
       <ion-list>
       <ion-item class="item-avatar item-icon-right" collection-repeat="x in y" href="#/pages/{{x.id}}">
        <img src="img/{{x.icon}}.png">
        <div style="position: absolute;   top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">{{x.name}}</div>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
```

**On Device**

[image: device screenshot]

Comment: Any feedbacks on my answer? Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to use this css:

```
.item-text-center
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and apply it to your `<div>`

```
<div class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">{{x.name}}</div>
```

and this is the whole content:

```
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" collection-repeat="x in y">
        <img src="img/{{x.icon}}.png">
        <div class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">{{x.name}}</div>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

This [ionic play](http://play.ionic.io/app/d1ae3566b133) might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. unfortunately i cannot vote up your answer.

Comment: Glad I've helped, Mariano. You can always up-vote me in the future :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

line-height works for me

```
css:
.item-text-center-vertical {
  line-height: 300%;
}

Inside avatar:
<h2 class="item-text-center-vertical">{{value}}</h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for everyone coming here from a search engine: today Ionic offers classes like Bootstrap to control flexbox alignment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#flex-properties