# Center text in ionic list-inset

Tags: css, list, ionic-framework

I am trying to simply center text in ionic `list-inset`. I tried adding `row-center` as some answers suggest. I also tried writing custom CSS like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921667/ionic-center-text-vertically-in-item-list-with-item-avatar-class). None of them have worked for me so far.

My code is below. Where should I go from here?

```
<ion-content ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="list list-inset">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        <div class="row row-center">
          <div class="col col-25">Ticker</div>
          <div class="col col-25">Price</div>
          <div class="col col-25">Shares</div>
          <div class="col col-25">Value</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label class="item" ng-repeat="item in sData">
        <div class="row row-center">
          <div class="col col-25">{{item.ticker}}</div>
          <div class="col col-25">{{item.price}}</div>
          <div class="col col-25">{{item.shares}}</div>
          <div class="col col-25">{{item.value}}</div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `row-center` try `text-center`